# Angular Unittest (jasmine, karma) how to test the @Input() is inserted to the html element

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm writing some unit test for my register component. In this component i have a html Element:

```
<form class="register-form" [formGroup]="registerForm">
    <mat-form-field>
         .....
    </mat-form-field>
   ...
</form>
```

I want to write 3 tests, first that checks the class of my form element, one that passes if registerForm isDefined and another one that passes if registerForm is injected to the form of class="register-form".

My tests:

```
describe('register-form',() => {
   it('register-form should have class: register-form', () => {
     expect(registerForm.className).toBe('register-form');
   });
   it('component should have defined formGroup: registerForm', () => {
     expect(registerComponent.registerForm).toBeDefined();
   });
});
```

I'm missing the connection-test from registerForm => formGroup of my form element. How can I write this test?

Shortly: I wan't to access the Property formGroup of the HTMLElement .

Comment: Then test `registerForm`'s value. avoid testing things the Angular team already tested.

Comment: Yes i can do that, but all test would pass if i dont assign registerForm to the formGroup. 

```<form class="register-form">
    <mat-form-field>
         .....
    </mat-form-field>
   ...
</form> ```  would issue a passed test.

Comment: What is inside of `<mat-form-field>...</mat-form-field>`?

Comment: inside of<mat-form-field> is an <input> elment with a formControlName.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the input element with a CSS selector and check the value of it.

```
it('register-form should have class: register-form', () => {
   let input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
   let el = input.nativeElement;

    expect(el.value).toBe('expected value');
});
```

more information is under: [Angular Testing Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-basics#bycss)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, buti think you misunderstood my question. I don't want to test the value of my input element. I want to test the injection of the formGroup attribute in the form class="register-form". 

So that a test fails if somebody removes the injection [formGroup]="registerForm" of my <form> element. But thanks for the link, I'll read that.

Comment: but if someone removes the [formGroup] directive the value of the input won't be there

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered the solution for my problem.
I just create a mock for a hosting component.

```
describe('componentUnderTest', () => {
  @Component({
selector: `host-component`,
template: `<component-under-test [testInput]="testInput">
</component-under-test >`
 })
 class TestHostComponent {


       public testInput: string = '';
   } 
}
```

After that I created this test

```
it('deviceUnderTest should have @Input() decorator on testInput', () => {
        testHostComponent.testInput='testString';
        testHostFixture.detectChanges();
        expect(testHostFixture.debugElement.query(By.css('component-under-test'))
        .componentInstance['testInput']).toEqual('testString');
      });
```